# JS : In while + nested for loop, is it better to re-instantiate or to reset value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, for-loop, while-loop

I'm not familiar with the js ecosystem and came across the following questioning: In a while loop, I do this: I have a for loop which pushes elements into an array. At the end of the for loop, I do something with the array. Rinse and repeat.

Is it better, performance wise to reinstantiate my array (example1) at the beginning of my while loop, or is it better to reset its value (example2)? Why?

Assume while and for both loop a huge number of time.

Example1:

```
while(condition) {
  const myArray=[];
  for(int i=0;i<X;i++){
    myArray.push(i);
  }
  doStuff(myArray);
}
```

Example2:

```
let myArray=[];
while(condition) {
  for(int i=0;i<X;i++){
    myArray.push(i);
  }
  doStuff(myArray);
  myArray=[]
}
```

I'm starting to dig the subject but it feel like this is the kind of question where 1) experts may have a quick and precise answer 2) other newcomers may be interested in... So here I am.

Comment: The answer will be in performing measurements inside the thing you're making, and then only make adjustments if the performance is too slow.

Comment: If I understand well, the performences of what I do (push et doStuff) will depend on how I initialized my array and/or if I reset its value?